# Handling updates to a specific file at the same time

Tags: git

Here is my scenario in git. I have a specific file that gets updated by two developers during a process. Lets say original contents of Xml are like this.

```
   <Type>
     <Base name = "name1" />
   </Type>
   <Personal>
      <Time name=one id=424 />
      <Time name=two id=433 />
      <Time name=three id=633 />
   </Personal>
```

Tool running on Dev A -> Checked out a branch br_test. Adds the following content to a specific xml file.

```
<Base name = "name2">
```

Tool running on Dev B -> Checked out the same branch br_test. Adds the following content to a specific xml file.

```
<Base name = "name3">
```

Now, they push at the same time. One of them gets through. Other one has to pull first and push again. Here is my question.

1. Since this is an automated tool that's doing this, I don't know how to handle the merge conflicts. Merging will be different for different contents of file too. For ex, When Base element is added, I want it appended to the xml. When Time name=<> element is added, I want it to overwrite.
2. Looking at how complicate that could be, I was wondering if there is a different way. Something like I lock/take ownership of the file so that others cant update. I read that this is not possible in git and everyone is against it.

So, what are my other options?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

**What would your automated tool do if Dev B started working after Dev A's work?**

That's the question you answer when resolving your conflicts - assuming Dev A pushed first and Dev B got the conflicts.

If you can't answer that, then the best would be to completely ignore Dev B's changes, `git checkout` Dev A's work and re-do all B's work over there. That's the only way to be sure you won't have any issue.

After a while you should learn what that XML files mean, and then you'll be able to resolve the conflicts. But - if you don't know what the correct result of the conflict should be, how would you expect the tool to know?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is something like I ended up coding. If dev A's work was available, then I would need to rerun the script to update the file again. So when I push fails, I pull and rerun my code and then push.